# Pasting from a textarea into a Word Doc

Tags: javascript, html, ms-word

I've scoured the web but all I've been able to find is pasting FROM a word doc INTO a textbox or textarea. What i'm trying to achieve is when I click a button which will open a Word Doc, it will automatically insert the values into a report with 16 different sections. Each section or category if you like has a corresponding section within the textarea. So there's two aspects of this question:

- Is it possible to open a specified word doc from a button on a webpage?
- Is it possible to link up the values with their corresponding sections in the word doc?

If anyone has any useful links or a more efficient way of doing this, I'm all ears, thanks.

Comment: it should be possible server side, that after clicking the button you generate the word doc with the values you need using e.g. php and return it to the user to save. In browser it's difficult, cause each browser is different and not all people have word installed on their machine.

Comment: @wmk I've decided to use a pop up instead and the user can just print from a web page, seems the be the easiest approach, thanks